# Progress bar with AsyncTask Object on initial app load

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask

I have looked around on the API and through a few questions on here, and I think I am on the right path. My app is based on a `webView` object and the initial load has quite a few cached pages so I want progressDialog on the initial start up instead of the blank black screen. Right now the app just crashes but I believe it is because I am creating and calling the AsyncTask object in the wrong place. Right now it is being called in the `onCreate()` method. I’m not new to Java but I am new to Android and this idea of not working with a `main()` function is confusing to me.

So where should I call the `execute()` function if I only want the `ProgressDialog` shown on the initial launch? And is my `AsyncTask` object even set up correctly?

```
public class site extends Activity {
private WebView engine;
private String urlSave;
private WebViewClient yourWebClient;
private ProgressDialog initLoadDialog;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    yourWebClient = new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains("tel:") == true) { 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
                startActivity(intent); 
            }
            else if(url.contains(“blah") == true && url.contains(“blah2") == false) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            else if(url.contains(“blah3") == true) {
                double[] loc = getGPS();
                url += "&cLat=" + loc[0] + "&cLong=" + loc[1];
                view.loadUrl(url);  
            }
            else {
                /*Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("url")); 
                startActivity(browserIntent);*/
            }
        return true;
        }
    };
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    progressSetup();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void progressSetup () {
    initLoadDialog = new ProgressDialog(site.this);
    initLoadDialog.setMessage("A message");
    initLoadDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    initLoadDialog.setMax(100);
    initLoadDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    urlLoad loading = new urlLoad();
    loading.execute();
} 
private class urlLoad extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
            engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            engine.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            engine.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
            engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            engine.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            engine.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
            engine.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            engine.loadUrl(“albhal");
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        initLoadDialog.setProgress(engine.getProgress());
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You might not be familiar with `adb logcat` shell command. It tells you were and why your app is crashing. That'd help a lot her ;)

Comment: sounds awesome, is it apart of the android SDK?

Comment: It is. Located in the platform-tools folder.

Comment: You also get a color version in eclipse by the way. Actually, chances are that you already have the logcat tab view in eclipse and did not notice it...

Answer (score 0):

Check your adb log, the error will pretty much explain to you what you didn't do right.
There's a lot of bad practice in your code. For example you call setContentView() in two Methods with different Layouts. The Flow of a android application is to call "onCreate", then "onStart". There is no reason to distinguish between those methods for you. Merge them and decide which layout to populate.
Also it is recommended to change the user-interface (this means also the dialogs) through the managing activity. In your case you are creating a ProgressDialog in the activity which then gets modified by the task. This is something you should avoid.

Comment: Well I made a different layout for the initial loading screen, I take there is a way to do it in one layout? I wanted to switch the layouts after the loading was done.

Comment: If you want to have two different layouts you should use two different activitys for that. You can switch between them using an intent. One activty would show the loading screen and switch to the next activity when the content is loaded. Theres not much code to put into these two activitys, but it will give you a clear structure. As I said, it's bad practice, however, that doesn't mean you can't do it your way.